# Advantages of using PubsubIO.writeStrings() in Apache Beam

Tags: java, pipeline, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Apache Beam provides the `PubsubIO.writeStrings()` method which returns a `PTransform` that can be used to write messages to Pubsub directly from a `PCollection`: [Example](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO/writeStrings?snippet=5ce6df522fd3800004e86aec).

Are there any obvious advantages of using this instead of writing a custom `DoFn` which writes messages (Example, DoFn of [this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publish_messages))?

Answer (score 0):

`PubsubIO.writeStrings` is a native [output connector](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/) proposed by `Beam`.

A `DoFn` is a usual transformation in `Beam` and can be used in each step.

If you don't a specific need, it's better using the native IO with `Beam` to not reinvent the wheel and use the supports that they offer.

This [link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-overview/) can help if you have to create a custom IO.